# TypeError: Class constructor {class} cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: npm, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

When running a create-react-app app with react-bootstrap installed, I am getting this error below when trying to add a Button

[image: TypeError: Class constructor Button cannot be invoked without 'new']

My imports are like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button } from "bootstrap";
import { PureComponent } from "react";
```

and the render code:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header />
        <Button>Test</Button>
        ...
```

I have looked into lots of other questions talking about Babel, Webpack, and a compiler config. But I am not seeing all these configurations inside my create-react-app.

Answer (score 23):

So, I found the problem. After 1 hour lost.
The mistake was on the suggested import that I've added.

**Wrong:**

```
import { Button } from "bootstrap";
```

**Right:**

```
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due the way I export my class.

At the end of my class file I added `export default ClassName()` instead of just `export default ClassName` without parenthesis.